# Standard Model: Problem with Masses of Elementary Particles?

Tags: particle-physics, mass, standard-model, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance

In his book "Modern Particle Physics", Mark Thomson explains two problems with masses of elementary particles in the SM:

(i) If we take the QED Lagrangian $\mathcal L = \bar{\psi}\left( i\gamma^{\mu}D_{\mu} - m\right)\psi - \frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$, where $D_{\mu} = \partial_{\mu} + iqA_{\mu}$ is the covariant derivative. Introducing a mass term of the form $\frac{1}{2}m^2_{\gamma}A_{\mu}A^{\mu}$ would break the required invariance under $U(1)$. This I understand so far.

(ii) On page 469, in Chapter 17.4, he writes:

> The problem with particle masses is not restricted to the gauge bosons. Writing the electron spinor field as $\psi = e$, the electron mass term in QED Lagrangian can be writtern in terms of the chiral particle states as $$-m_{e}\bar{e}e = -m_{e}\bar{e}\left[ \frac{1}{2}\left( 1-\gamma^{5}\right) + \frac{1}{2}\left( 1+\gamma^{5}\right) \right]e$$

Short comment from my side: On page 142, he wrote that:

> [...] any spinor $u$ can be decomposed into left- and right-handed chiral components with
> $$ u = \frac{1}{2}\left( 1+\gamma^{5}\right)u + \frac{1}{2}\left( 1-\gamma^{5}\right)u. $$

Okay, continuing with the calculation on p. 469:

> $$-m_{e}\bar{e}e = [...] = -m_{e}\bar{e}\left[ \frac{1}{2}\left( 1-\gamma^{5}\right)e_{L} + \frac{1}{2}\left( 1+\gamma^{5}\right)e_{R} \right] = -m_{e}\left( \bar{e}_{R}e_{L} + \bar{e}_{L}e_{R} \right) \quad (17.16)$$
> In the SU(2)$_{L}$ gauge transformation of the weak interaction, left-handed particles transform as weak isospin doublets and right-handed particles as singlets, and therefore the mass term of $(17.16)$ breaks the required gauge invariance.

**Question:**

How can we understand his last sentence?

Answer (score 0):

If we take the mass term $-m_{e}\bar{e}e$ and apply an SU(2)$_{L}$ gauge transformation $U$, we get: $$U\left( -m_{e}\bar{e}e\right) = -m_{e}U\bar{e}e \overset{(17.16)}{=} -m_{e}U\left( \bar{e}_{R}e_{L} + \bar{e}_{L}e_{R} \right) = -m_{e}\left\{ \left(U\bar{e}_{R}\right)e_{L} + \bar{e}_{R}\left(Ue_{L}\right) + \left(U\bar{e}_{L}\right)e_{R} + \bar{e}_{L}\left(Ue_{R}\right)\right\}.$$
Now, we know that the weak charged-current interaction only couples to left-handed chiral particle states and right-handed chiral anti-particle states. Thus, the last two terms have to vanish, and we get: $$-m_{e}U\bar{e}e = -m_{e}\left\{ \left(U\bar{e}_{R}\right)e_{L} + \bar{e}_{R}\left(Ue_{L}\right) \right\} \overset{!}{=} -m_{e}\bar{e}e \overset{(17.16)}{=} -m_{e}\left( \bar{e}_{R}e_{L} + \bar{e}_{L}e_{R} \right)$$ Carefully comparing the last equation, we see that gauge invariance is not given, and we thus need the Higgs mechanism.